# Cooperation in asymmetric Prisoners Dilemma

Tags: reference-request, game-theory, economics

There are 2 players, each can choose 2 actions, a or b. The payoffs in each case are given by rules

Actions (a,a) -> payoffs (3,4)
Actions (a,b) -> payoffs (0,5)
Actions (b,a) -> payoffs (4,0)
Actions (b,b) -> payoffs (2,1)

This is a slightly perturbed version of the classical Prisoners Dilemma, but the crucial difference is that players can talk to each other and agree the strategy, and that the payoffs are transferable. It is obvious that, in this case, they should agree on strategy (a,a) with highest total pay-off 7, and then divide the resulting 7 between them in a fair way.

The question is - how to divide 7? Are there any kinds of game theory which can help here?

Non-cooperative game theory suggests Nash equilibrium (b,b) with payoffs (2,1), which is completely unreasonable decision if cooperation is allowed.

Player 1 may suggest to use cooperative game theory, with value function v(1,2)=7, v(1)=2, and v(2)=1, where the last 2 equalities follow from the Nash equilibrium, and then use Shapley value to divide 7, resulting in higher payoff for player 1. However, player 2 may argue that, in general, defining value function based on Nash equilibrium cannot work, at least because Nash equilibrium need not to be unique, not to mention other reasons.

Instead, player 2 may suggest that if the game would be played repeatedly, both players would eventually learn that it is better to use (a,a) with payoffs (3,4), and he could get a higher profit. Player 1 may object that non-cooperative theory of iterated Prisoners Dilemma is not applicable, because in this case the game is played only once, players can cooperate, and, after all, the pair of strategies maximizing the total payoff may not be unique in general.

So, once again, is there a branch of game theory which is perfectly applicable to the situations as above and can clearly suggest how to divide 7?

Comment: You can decompose the game matrix into a symmetric (cooperative) part and an antisymmetric (zero-sum) part. The value of the cooperative part is just the maximum, the value of the zero-sum part is minimax, the value of the overall game is the sum of these two contributions. See http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/adum/publications/Cooperation_in_strategic_games_revisited.pdf